# Devise: Redirect to "/signup" on registration failure

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I wanted to redirect to "/signup" page after a user fails the registration process. How do you do it?

Every time the registration fails, it redirects to "/users" which is not what I wanted, I want it to redirect to the registration page.

TIA

Comment: Probably related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6240141/devise-redirect-on-sign-up-failure

Comment: how do you detect that something went wrong in the registration?

Answer (score 0):

You have to write a custom method in the initializer and call it.

See this post here, hope it gets you where you need to!

[Devise redirect after login fail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5832631/devise-redirect-after-login-fail)